# How to render partial haml on controller in padrino?

Tags: ajax, haml, padrino

I'm doing a ajax request. The backend might render a partial haml and return it. I'm getting this error

> Padrino::Rendering::TemplateNotFound at /feedhtml

backend code

```
render :partial => 'feedhtml', :layout => false
```

Also I tried a tons of variation of this code.

Answer (score -1):

can you check the right folder where you put feedhtml? now it searchs in views/  is that what you want?

check the subfolder.

```
render :partial => 'partial/feedhtml', :layout => false
```

if you files is in

views/partial/feedhtml

Comment: Please don't misuse the answer feature to ask for clarification or make non-answer remarks. Use comments for that instead. If you can't comment yet, get the necessary reputation to do so by answering clear questions until then.